# обращение к файлу

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Следующий скрипт говорит что файл существует(а он существует)

```
<?php 
echo(file_exists("\\myserv\myfile.txt")?"да":"нет")
?>
```

Но если мы разместим эту строчку в контроллере ларавела и запустим на апаче, то узнаем, что его нет. Что интересно, если запустить с помощью команды php artisan serve, то опять выдаст положительный результат.
Как указывать абсолютный путь файла в коде при запуске на апаче?

Comment: проще залинковать директорию на сервере в ФС сайта, чтобы не зависеть на уровне кода от имени/IP адреса сервера. либо выносить это в конфиг.

Comment: "либо выносить это в конфиг..." э-эээ, а чуть поподробнее можно? У меня это первый опыт )) "проще залинковать директорию на сервере в ФС сайта", я подцепил папку тоталом как сетевой диск, это про это было? Но при обращении через этот диск, тоже не находит.

Comment: не даст вам апач выйти за пределы директории папки сайта. речь шла про символические ссылки.  в винде это примерно `cmd -> mklink. /D folder \\server\folder`

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: Информацию о символической ссылке с помощью функции Lstat(__DIR__ .'\folder') я получаю, но file_exists  (__DIR__ .'\folder\myfile.txt' ) возвращает false

Comment: вы проверили. что ссылка правильная и вы реально по ней перейдя в нужную директорию попадаете? А то ссылку то вы создали, и инфу о ней как о файле можете получить, но если она указывает не несуществующий путь, то конечно дальше работать ничего не будет

Comment: при клике на ссылку захожу в папку где находится файл